# How do I fix this error I'm getting trying to include Dark Mode with CSS?

Tags: css

I am trying to make Dark Mode for my website, but my CSS file kept on saying:

- to include an `RBRACE ( } )` for every line
- line 9 is saying put a colon in character 5
- it says rule is empty for lines 5, 16, and 20
- for line 36, it says `Expected (<color> | inherit) but found 'var(--text-color)'`
- for line 26, it says that 'The universal selector (*) is known to be slow."

Does anyone know how to fix this mess?

Thanks in advance for responding.

Here is my code for reference.

```
body {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;

body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* defaults to dark theme */
  body {
    --text-color: #eee;
    --bkg-color: #121212;
  }
  body.light-theme {
    --text-color: #222;
    --bkg-color: #fff;
  }
}

* {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: var(--bkg-color);
}

h1,
p {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your top `body {}` rule is missing its closing `}`.

Change this:

```css
body {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;

body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}
```

to this:

```css
body {
  --text-color: #222;
  --bkg-color: #fff;
}                             /* <-- here */

body.dark-theme {
  --text-color: #eee;
  --bkg-color: #121212;
}
```

---

- However, your stylesheet still has repeating values, you can normalize it somewhat by defining your actual color values only on the `:root` (aka `html`):

  - And then referencing them from within both `@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {` and `body.dark-theme`, which means UA-based color schemes can work as well as JS-based overrides too.

    - Because the DOM still doesn't have an API to set color scheme for some reason.
- Also, you don't need a `* { font-family: }` rule, just set it on `body`.

  - And `Helvetica` should come before `Arial` because [Helvetica *just looks better*](https://pimpmytype.com/arial-vs-helvetica/).

```css
/* #region Light/Dark Scheme Properties */

:root {
  --text-color-light: #222;
  --bkg-color-light : #fff;

  --text-color-dark : #eee;
  --bkg-color-dark  : #121212;

  /* Default to the light scheme (before `prefers-color-scheme` and/or `body.dark-theme` are applied): */
  --text-color      : var(--text-color-light);
  --bkg-color       : var(--bkg-color-light);
}

@media (prefers-color-scheme: dark) {
  /* For UA color scheme: */
  body {
    --text-color: var(--text-color-dark);
    --bkg-color : var(--bkg-color-dark);
  }
}
body.dark-theme {
  /* For CSS-class/JS-based color scheme override: */
  --text-color: var(--text-color-dark);
  --bkg-color : var(--bkg-color-dark);
}

/* If you want to add a CSS clas `.light-theme` to *override* prefers-color-scheme: dark, then uncomment this: */
/*
body.light-theme {
  /* For CSS-class/JS-based color scheme override: */
  --text-color: var(--text-color-light);
  --bkg-color : var(--bkg-color-light);
}
*/

/* #endregion Light/Dark Scheme Properties */

/*
    *DO NOT* reference any of the `-dark` or `-light` properties at all below this point.
    You only need to reference the non-suffixed custom-properties, as those will always be set to the current *effective* color scheme's values, whether from  `prefers-color-scheme` or by `.dark-theme` (or `.light-theme`).
*/

body {
  background-color: var(--bkg-color);
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}

h1,
p {
  color: var(--text-color);
}
```